# Moving the firefox button and tab bar as per when maximised

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

I've just spotted than when maximised the new Firefox button in Firefox 4 is positioned like the image below; with the Firefox button, tabs, tab group button and min/max/close buttons all sharing the same horizontal space:

[image: position of Firefox button in Firefox 4 RC when window is maximised]

But I have a wide-screen monitor and so don't keep Firefox maximised - I keep it open over the right 60%, or so, of the screen - and when the window *isn't* maximised, the button is positioned as per the shot below, which consumes more vertical space, and now that I've seen the more compact version, I *want* the more compact version *all the time*.

[image: position of Firefox button in Firefox 4 RC when window is free]

**Is there any way to utilise the "maximised" button and tab positions on a non-maximised window?**

---

The closest thing I've found is the [Movable Firefox Button](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/movable-firefox-button/) add-on, which changes the button's position but *doesn't* recover the lost vertical space, so (I think) actually ends up looking worse than the normal version when not maximised...

[image: [position of Firefox button in Firefox 4 RC, with "Movable Firefox Button" plug-in, when window is free]

Comment: I'm not sure whether Windows supports this for non-maximised windows. It could be the reason that the feature currently only works for maximised windows, and if true it would mean that you can't do what you want to do. This is merely a hunch, though.

Comment: @Tomalak, tbh, that was my initial thought, but then how do they get the Firefox button up there? :)

Comment: Vista/Win7 will support it in the same way that they support the application button for Ribbon UI. It's just an extension of the traditional application titlebar icon. I think. (Note that, as far as I can tell, the "Movable Firefox Button" _cannot_ be moved to the titlebar; you have to disable it to go back to the "native" menu-on-the-titlebar mechanism.)

Comment: @Tomalak, a good point. FYI, the button-in-titlebar works on XP as well (eg, http://i.imgur.com/HJDO1.png and http://i.imgur.com/G4gIs.png when using FF4 portable at work), and I guess the ribbon does as well (although I can't test)?. And you're correct about the movable button causing you to lose the ability to place the button in the in the titlebar, I've already stopped using it for that reason.

Comment: Good intel about XP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want tabs to be in the Title Bar(in Tabs on Top Mode) even on Non-Maxmized windows use userstyle http://userstyles.org/styles/42417/

Comment: And there it is, awesome. It makes the Firefox button smaller, which I personally don't like - it looks squashed - but a quick tweak of the style and [job done](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oufQP.png)!

Comment: However, it should be noted by anyone who gives this user-style a spin on **Windows XP** that it looks like [Bad Things™](http://i.stack.imgur.com/StOjJ.png) happen to the minimise/restore/close buttons if you use this...